# Target Host Error, while post a HTTP-Request

Tags: android, json, authentication, http-post, httpresponse

**What I try to do**

---

I'm trying to create a Loginmask for my App. To check if a userslogin is correct I create a HTTP-Post(JSON) to my server, from there I get response if the user is in the db-table or not.

For the moment the HTTP-POST dosn't work, I allways get this Error:

```
12-26 14:02:22.871: W/System.err(869): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=api.i-v-o.ch
```

This seems really strange in my eyes because i defined the URL-Path.

**Question**

---

Like you saw, the problem is that i can't etablish a Network Connection. Please tell me where the error is in my code, that I can fix it.

It would be also really great, if you could provide me a good tutorial for this, or a codesample, that I can fix the error on my own.

Thx for your help in Advance.

Down here you find the Code of my Activity and my DataHandler.

LoginActivity.class:

```
package de.ivocore;

import de.ivocore.service.DataHandler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public DataHandler JSONLogin = new DataHandler();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //Text-Felder 
        final EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        final EditText pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        //Button
        Button loginbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login);



        //OnClickListner für den Button definieren
        loginbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                //Strings definieren
                final String usertxt = user.getText().toString();
                final String pwdtxt = pwd.getText().toString();

                if (usertxt != null && pwdtxt != null){
                JSONLogin.JSONLogin(usertxt, pwdtxt);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Bitte Username und Passwort eingeben!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

DataHandler.class

```
package de.ivocore.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataHandler {

    /** LOGIN-Methode
     * Für diese Methode muss ein "final String username" sowie ein "final String password" mitgegeben werden
     * Die Methode fürt die Login-Prozedur mit dem api.i-v-o.ch durch.
     * Zurückgeben wird die Response welche vom Server kommt (Login erfolgreich oder nicht), sowie der Sessionkey.
     *  */
    public void JSONLogin(final String username, final String password){


        Thread t = new Thread(){                                                            //Neuen Thread definieren


            public void run(){                                                                  //Startet automatisch wenn der Thread gestartet wird, führt die Funktion aus


                String URL = "api.i-v-o.ch";                                                            //URL definieren für JSON-Post
                Looper.prepare();                                                                       //Erstellt den Nachrichten-Pool
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                                            //HttpClient definieren, handelt den http datenverkehr
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);                   //Timeout Limite
                HttpResponse response;                                                                  //HttpResponse definieren, handelt den http response
                JSONObject login = new JSONObject();                                                    //JSON-Object welches gesendet wird

                try{
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);                                                  //HttpPost definieren, handelt den http post
                    login.put("username", username);                                                    //Füget dem JSONObject Login den Username ein
                    login.put("password", password);                                                    //Fügt dem JSONObject Login das Passwort ein

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("Login" + login.toString());                     //StringEntity definieren und StringEntity aus dem JSONObject Login erstellen
                    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);                                                                 //Hier wird der Post an das IVO-Core gesendet
                    response = client.execute(post);                                                    //Hier wird die Response abgefangen


                    /** Response-Checker
                     * Hier wird gecheckt was wir in der Response bekommen
                     */
                    if(response != null){                                                               //Hier wird geprüft ob etwas in der Response ist

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                                         //Stringbuilder um aus dem Response einen String zu erstellen
                        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));   //response vom inputstreamreader lesen und in einen bufferedreader einfügen um diesen anschliessend zu einem string hinzuzuzfügen und in ein json object umwandeln

                        String line;                                                                    //String definieren darin ist die später die response
                        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {                                        //Hier wird definiert das der String Line den inhalt vom bufferedreader ist, der duchgand wird mit readLine durchgeführt
                            sb.append(line + "\n");                                                     //Hier wird der string line nach \n gesplittet (newline)
                            }

                        String result;                                                                  //String result definieren
                        result = sb.toString();                                                         //Hier wird der inhalt vom Stringbuilder zum String result hinzugefühgt
                        Log.d("DataHandler", "Append String " + result);                                //Gibt aus was im result drin ist


                    }

                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("DataHandler", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                }
                Looper.loop();                                                                          //Nachrichten loopen
            }
        };
        t.start();                                                                                      //Thread starten
    }

}
```

---

**Logcat:**

```
12-26 14:00:29.331: W/System.err(869): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=api.i-v-o.ch
12-26 14:00:29.331: W/System.err(869):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
12-26 14:00:29.331: W/System.err(869):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
12-26 14:00:29.331: W/System.err(869):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-26 14:00:29.331: W/System.err(869):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-26 14:00:29.331: W/System.err(869):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-26 14:00:29.341: W/System.err(869):  at de.ivocore.service.DataHandler$1.run(DataHandler.java:51)
12-26 14:00:29.341: E/DataHandler(869): Cannot Estabilish Connection
12-26 14:02:22.871: W/System.err(869): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=api.i-v-o.ch
12-26 15:09:44.431: W/System.err(936): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.i-v-o.ch": No address associated with hostname
12-26 15:09:44.441: W/System.err(936):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:426)
12-26 15:09:44.441: W/System.err(936):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
12-26 15:09:44.441: W/System.err(936):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
12-26 15:09:44.441: W/System.err(936):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
12-26 15:09:44.441: W/System.err(936):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-26 15:09:44.451: W/System.err(936):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-26 15:09:44.451: W/System.err(936):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-26 15:09:44.451: W/System.err(936):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-26 15:09:44.481: W/System.err(936):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-26 15:09:44.501: W/System.err(936):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-26 15:09:44.501: W/System.err(936):  at de.ivocore.service.DataHandler$1.run(DataHandler.java:51)
12-26 15:09:44.501: W/System.err(936): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
12-26 15:09:44.511: W/System.err(936):  at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
12-26 15:09:44.511: W/System.err(936):  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
12-26 15:09:44.511: W/System.err(936):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:411)
12-26 15:09:44.511: W/System.err(936):  ... 10 more
12-26 15:09:44.511: E/DataHandler(936): Cannot Estabilish Connection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "http://" to `"api.i-v-o.ch"`

So it should be: "http://api.i-v-o.ch"